# using DI (Unity) with MVVM and XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've got a pretty good idea how to use Unity to instantiate the MainWindow of a WPF application and how to inject dependencies into the top level of my application using the UnityContainer.  What I'm missing is how to use this approach in a multi-layered design.

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
        {
            DataSet dataModel = new DataSet();
            dataModel.Tables.Add(new DataTable("User"));
            dataModel.Tables["User"].Rows.Add(dataModel.Tables["User"].NewRow());
            container.RegisterInstance<IDataModel>(dataModel);
            var window = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
            window.Show();
        }
    }
```

For example, I have a 'User' ComboBox control that appears in any number of dialogs and grid controls.  This 'User' Combobox uses a 'UserCollection' view model which has a dependency on a common data model (for all intents and purposes, a shared DataSet used by all dialogs and grid controls).  Since the main window doesn't control the construction of the Grid Controls or the XAML defined controls, how do I inject my common data model into this reusable 'UserCollection' View Model?

Comment: I have this type of thing a lot and of the various alternatives I try and opt for plugin module where the 'common data model' gets registered with a container controlled lifetime.  Secondarily, I would use a state which is shared by all Vm's.  Lastly I would use the service locator (although reluctantly).  Is that of any use?

Comment: Garry, no, it's not of any use unless you can provide some concrete ideas behind these generic instructions.  What container do you use?  How does a dialog box or grid control access the container?  Does this pattern use a static container or service locator?

Comment: Your questions: I use Unity. Each ViewModel has a constructor which requires the container instance as an argument, and the VM's themselves are "RESOLVED" (as opposed to created) by Unity.  Since Unity also knows about the 'common data model', each VM can RESOLVE on it and access it, but I like Unity to resolve on it when each VM is constructed.  Lastly, the pattern uses neither a static container nor a service locator, instead it's classical DI front to back.  Everything's done in the type registration phase.  Is that more helpful?

Comment: I didn't want to put in sample code until I'm sure it would be helpful.  It would also be a very modest code that highlighted the central issue, it would not be the whole enchillada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the [MVVM design pattern](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html), and [using an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). In a view model first approach, your dependencies will be injected into your view models, and your view models would expose properties that are bound to by the view.

So for example, to populate your `ComboBox` on your view from a shared resource, you would probably want to inject some form of service or repository (or unit of work) that retrieves your items into the view model:

```
public class MyViewModel(IUserRepository userRepository)
{
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

private void PointAtWhichYouWantToPopulateTheCollection()
{
    this.Users = new ObservableCollection(this.userRepository.GetUsers());
}

public ObservableCollection<User> Users
{
    get 
    {
        return this.users;
    }

    set
    {
        this.users = value;
        // notify of property change here
    }
}
```

In your view, you would then bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` to the `Users` collection on the view model. In your implementation of IUserRepository, you would do your data access code. `GetUsers` for example may return an `IEnumerable<User>`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I am using the MVVM design pattern.  I need you to connect the dots for me.  Let's say my ComboBox has a view model called 'UserCollection'.  This 'UserCollection' ViewModel has a dependency on the shared DataSet and we're back to the original question: how do you instantiate this view model that is several layers down from the main window?

Comment: Answer updated. I would very strongly recommend that you use an MVVM framework.

Comment: OK.  Now let's say that we've got a dialog box called 'Manage Users'.  In this dialog box, we have the 'User' ComboBox which uses the 'MyViewModel' as it's view model (and binds to the 'Users' property).  My question is, given the declaration of 'dataModel' in the original post and given that we're using Unity, how do we instantiate MyViewModel in this dialog so that it uses the common DataSet?

Comment: Your implementation of the user service or repository will have the DataSet logic. You probably shouldn't be using DataSets but that's another discussion. If you want the same instance of the service to be used throughout the app then you would register it as a singleton, otherwise if you wish to share instances amongst a subset of view models then you can use view model factories.

Comment: (1) This is MVVM, not MVC.  What Repository are you talking about?  This is a simple pattern and I don't get the feeling like you've actually implemented Unity for it as you keep beating around the bush on this basic issue: how is the Unity container instance passed down to the dialog box in a simple MVVM application? (2) Why on earth would I not want to use DataSets?

Comment: 1) Yes I know it's MVVM, why do you think repositories are exclusive to MVC? I have used Unity and many other containers both in commercial and personal projects. The repository I'm referring to is the one clearly mentioned in my answer. 2) There are many methods of data access in the .NET space. You may want to consider an ORM for example. I've answered your question twice now, if you'd like to try and read with the intention of understanding rather than with the intention of replying.

Comment: I wish to extend my apologies to devdigital.  The discussion of a Repository was a red-herring, but his design is essentially correct.  The View Model is created using DI, then the XAML code binds to exposed elements of the View Model.  The XAML elements themselves should not, and can not, be given their own view models.  I wanted to make the controls self-contained so they could be re-used, but this is unrealistic in an MVVM design.  Best design is to make the control view models reusable, but they'll always need to be exposed through the owner view model.